# How to exclude groups based on condition in TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

I have around 10 testcase in Login module. I have to execute the test on Staging and Product environment but on Product environment, need to exclude some specific testcase which require some dummy data to be insert in application. For that i have added one group name `PRO_EXCLUDE` in my scenarios.

Refer the below example with combined group names which i need to exclude while executing.

```
SCENARIO: verify login landing page
META-DATA: {"TestCase_ID":"BP_L&R_001","description":"verify login landing page ","groups":["REGRESSION","PRO_EXCLUDE"]}    
    Given user is on homepage
    When clicks on login link
    Then verify page title text with title '${loginpage.title}'
END
```

And rest of method have only one group i.e. `REGRESSION`

I've configured the test in below manner

```
<test name="Login" enabled="true">
    <method-selectors>
        <method-selector>
            <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[ return groups.containsKey("REGRESSION") && groups.containsKey("PRO_EXCLUDE");]]></script>
        </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
    <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="scenarios/login.bdd" />

    <classes>
        <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

This executes the scenario which have `REGRESSION` and `PRO_EXCLUDE` group both. I don't want to execute this one but rest of Scenarios with only `REGRESSION` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach is to utilize meta-data feature of qaf. According to that rather than adding multiple groups, categorize them depending on nature. For example:

- Scope - Smoke, Regression
- Module - FunctionlModule1, FM2
- Channel - Web, API, Mobile

etc...

You need to define for your AUT and set in scenario as meta-data.

```
SCENARIO: verify login landing page
META-DATA: {"TestCase_ID":"BP_L&R_001","description":"verify login landing page ","scope":"REGRESSION","feature":"PRO_EXCLUDE"]}    
    Given user is on homepage
    When clicks on login link
    Then verify page title text with title '${loginpage.title}'
END
```

If you are authoring test case in java you can use `@MetaData` on test method to set test case meta-data. You can use meta-data filter by setting appropriate `include` and `exclude` property value as below:

```
include= {'scope': ['REGRESSION'], 'feature': ['PRO_EXCLUDE']}
```

It will include test cases/scenario which has meta-data `scope` whose value is `REGRESSION` **AND** `feature` whose value is `PRO_EXCLUDE`. Please refer [documentation](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario_metadatata_filter_include_exclude_prop.html) for more usage examples.

***NOTE***: To work this feature properly, you have to add method selector from qaf `com.qmetry.qaf.automation.testng.pro.QAFMethodSelector` in xml configuration file or in ant testng target or in maven pom. Groups is also considered as one of the meta-data by qaf.

Answer (score 0):

Below condition working for me :

```
<method-selectors>
    <method-selector>
        <script language="beanshell"><![CDATA[ return groups.containsKey("REGRESSION") && (!groups.containsKey("PRO_EXCLUDE"));]]></script>
    </method-selector>
</method-selectors>
```

Further solution will be great appreciated.